Are most sentences said or written only once?
I have many times heard it claimed that the great majority of natural-language sentences that are ever said or written are said or written only once. For example, Steven Pinker, in The Language Instinct, summarizing a famous argument by Noam Chomsky, says, "[V]irtually every sentence that a person utters or understands is a brand-new combination of words, appearing for the first time in the history of the universe."
Can you tell me some authoritative writing about this topic, such as a study of large corpora, which provides some insight and might include some interesting observations? I'm wary of trying to directly adjudicate the claim itself, since that likely depends on many details of how it is construed (e.g. whether it's about sentence "types" or "tokens", speech or writing, and perhaps much more). I'm looking to find something to read that looks into the topic seriously and in depth.
My efforts before posting this question:

I asked some AIs for authoritative writing about this topic and got some strange results. For example, perplexity.ai said, "There is no authoritative source to support the claim that nearly every sentence ever spoken is spoken only once. This claim appears to be an overgeneralization that is not backed by rigorous linguistic research."

I skimmed Corpus Linguistics and the Description of English by Hans Lindquist but I didn't find anything addressing whole-sentence frequency.

I counted all the sentences in the British National Corpus and found that of 6,026,276 sentences, 5,418,983 are unique. A cursory look at the duplicates suggests that a great many are actually section headings, like "EDUCATION", "Department:", "Introduction", "Act 1, Scene 1", not sentences as we ordinarily think of them.



Many of those 10^60 sentences are ungrammatical. Furthermore, they are not normally distributed. Instead, some (short) sentences like "Yes", "No", "Hi", and "How are you?" will be far more frequent, so you need to specify whether you are talking about the majority of sentence types or tokens. Finally, generative AI is well-known to hallucinate up sources out of thin air.

Where have you heard that stated?

Depends on the corpus and modality.  If you take StackExchange questions like yours, and split them into sentences, and query Google, then indeed most of them have never been written on the open web before.  But for messaging apps or spoken language, where sentences are shorter, the fat head is a bit larger.

@Lambie I've heard the claim stated in a variety of places over years, most of which I don't remember. I do remember one recurring source, though: arguments that language use is creative, especially to argue for Chomsky's theories of language against Skinner's view of reinforcement, since people speak sentences that haven't been reinforced. (Not to open this old argument here, of course.)

Frankly? Even a non-linguist would know that logically this idea of most natural language sentences being said only once is not tenable. Think of all the natural language utterances we use on a daily basis in English. Even sentences by a single speaker are likely to repeat over a short period of time. "What time are you leaving?", for instance.

@Araucaria I rolled back the change to the title, because I'm really asking for authoritative writing about the subject, not about the subject. The comments are already wandering into debate about the subject, which would require tedious clarification to address.

It’s difficult to provide authoritative sources for a doubtful claim.

I bet it’s true if you count unique sentences, not observations of a stream.

@BenKovitz No problem, but you may wish to consider the reason why I made the edit in the first place! Which is that after three days your question had already flatlined at 33 views :( . The extra 46 views you've had in the last 9 hours are presumably due to the temporary title change and activity it caused. I think you need to change the title to make it both clear and interesting for readers and stipulate the finer details in the question. You're going to get off topic comments (if anyone ever looks at the post again!) but a healthy number of views would mean you might get some good answers!

@BenKovitz Also, I'm certainly less likely to bother writing you an answer if only an eight extra visitors are ever going to read it!

I’m voting to close this question because the claim is untenable. Most of what people say (their utterances) in daily life is repeated over and over again throughout their lives.

@Lambie If that's true, it should be easy to demonstrate. And just because you can't (if you can't), there's no reason to stop anyone else from being able to!

I think the question should at least specify whether we are counting each sentence that is produced separately, or only distinct sentences (tokens or types). Without that the question is ambiguous. And it might be useful to address Adam’s point about modality as well. Without this, the question should probably be closed as “needs details or clarity”.

@Araucaria-him The question asks for something that is not possible to prove except through logic. We are not yet equipped with a listening device that listen to everyone's speech everyday everywhere in a particular language or place. How many times in your life have you written things like: Thank you for your email. 50 times?   Versus the sentence you just wrote in the previous comment? Have you ever used that sentence (or do you even know if you have) before??

@Keelan I expect that details about the question, like whether we're counting tokens or types, should be addressed in authoritative writing about the topic.

@Araucaria-him Oh well. I appreciate your effort to make the question more attractive. All I want to know, though, is something authoritative to read about the topic. I'd prefer to avoid raising details in the question, since I expect that coverage of the topic would explore those details. I guess that makes the question uninteresting, though.

@Araucaria-him OK, I rewrote it and added an item that might be interesting (#3 in the 2nd paragraph).

I’m voting to close this question because no reference is provided for the claim.

@curiousdannii OP has provided evidence from the BNC.

@BenKovitz Adding something in the body of the question is not going to get the question more viewers! You need to change the title! PS from research on the interweb, it appears the claim appears in Steven Pinker's The Language Instinct as well as in Blank Slate, birth of which you may wish to add to the body of the question should you wish to get it reopened.

@curiousdannii A lack of specific references does not negate the fact that this is a well-known, commonly-heard and oft-repeated notion. This isn’t [skeptics.se], and I don’t think we should be applying their style of requiring proof of specific, notable claims in order for questions to be considered on topic. Even more so, asking whether someone has treated a particular linguistic subject should not require providing references for the notability of the subject.

If it's been claimed many times then it won't be hard to add a citation, and then the question can be reopened. As other comments have said, what precisely is being claimed matters. Giving an exact quote will allow the question to be properly addressed.

@Araucaria-him OK, I just tried both your suggestion for a new title and your suggestion of including a quotation. Hopefully if anyone knows of authoritative writing about this, they won't be stopped from answering.

Though personally I'd say that citing Perplexity reflects poorly and would be better left out entirely. You can't effectively learn from AI because you can't trust what it says.

@BenKovitz Good stuff. (Hope you're not confusing me with CD, though ;-)). How did you find the duplicates in the BNC, btw?

@curiousdannii I don't trust what AI says, but I do sometimes use it as a superior form of Internet search, i.e. as a lead for something that I can check out separately. I've previously had success using it to find research papers, so I was surprised by this result. I wonder if there's a story behind it—perhaps writing purporting to debunk the uniqueness of most sentences.

@BenKovitz Come to think of it, doesn't your own research show Pinker's version of Chomsky's claim to be incorrect? Even in a small 6 million word corpus like the BNC, a whopping 10% of sentences were duplicates! (Especially considering the corpus is tilted towards texts with overly long sentences)

@Araucaria-him Nope, I was definitely following your suggestions. Thanks, for both your suggestions and your persistence! I found the duplicates in the BNC by downloading it and then writing a little Python program to read through it (using the nltk library). I was delighted to find that the documentation was quite good.

@BenKovitz What proportion of the duplicates were like that would you say?

You seem to be misinterpreting Pinker. When Pinker talks about “every sentence that a person utters or understands”, he is counting every occurrence. You are asking about “natural-language sentences that are ever said or written” which indicates that you are not counting occurrences but distinct sentences. If I say A,A,B,C, for Pinker 50% of these are unique (B,C but not A,A), but for your formulation, two thirds are unique (B,C but not A).

@Keelan Who is your comment directed to?

@Keelan I've edited the question once again to clarify why I'm not specifying sentence types vs. tokens. I understand that a precise conceptualization need not be a precondition of a question; even conceptual confusion is OK. Rather, a good answer can explicitly address how to conceptualize it—Araucaria's answer, for example.

@Araucaria-him Since we're veering into discussion, which I'm curious to explore further, I just started "The first chatroom of its kind in the history of the universe". When I was creating it, SE at first objected, "This room might already exist."

If utterances were unique, a kid could not learn a language or language. It's precisely the hearing by the child of repeated patterns that makes them learn them. Whether wired in or not (Pinker v. Chomsky), there are patterns of repeated utterances in daily life.

@Lambie that logic is off, it seems to me. There can be repeated patterns without repeated entire utterances.

@Keelan I don't understand people commenting here. "What did you say?".  Often, parental utterances are the most repetitive. Also, when you learn a language, most of the phrases are completely repetitive. Where do you live? Do you speak English?

@Lambie I agree that many utterances are not unique, but not that “If utterances were unique, a kid could not learn a language or language”.

While I can't give an answer, here are some things that we might want to think about and which it should be easier to find literature on:
All languages?
Firstly, are we talking about all natural languages? The languages concerned may have a dramatic effect on average sentence length and types of complexity. If it is indeed the case that there are languages which effectively don't allow embedding (or in which it is severely limited), such as Piraha, then those languages will have a smaller number of words per sentence and there is more overall likelihood of sentences being repeated. Furthermore, languages like Turkish will have fewer words per sentence than a language like English. You'll also have to consider research about how inflection affects the probability of a sentence being repeated. For example, pro-drop language in which adjectives show gender agreement will have less repeated sentences than pro-drop languages which don't. In the former sentences like "it's loquacious/blue/interesting/bellicose" will be split into two (or more) groups depending on the gender of the subject making them less likely to be repeated and the latter they won't.
Age:
Secondly, are we talking about all humans or only adults and so on and so forth? Small children use very short sentences compared to adults (even when they are fully grammatical) and they also have a much more highly constrained vocabulary, so one suspects that, perhaps excluding the use of names, most of an English speaking toddler's sentences have been uttered before or will be uttered again. In Nigeria 42% of the population are under 14 and so the inclusion or exclusion of children's sentences will have quite some impact on how likely a Nigerian Hausa-speaking person's sentences are to be repeated or to have already been said. On a less dramatic scale, older adult speakers of English appear to use shorter sentences with a more limited vocabulary than younger adult speakers  - thus making their sentences more likely to be repeated. So, if for some reason children's sentences were to be excluded, where the cut-off point occurs may potentially have a significant effect.
Which corpus?
Thirdly, regarding the reliability of any data that one might decide to use to come to a conclusion about this, we need to consider what type of texts the data is coming from. The type of corpora that are currently available are very unlikely to be of any use here. Most large corpora of spoken language are not corpora of natural conversation or conversations at the supermarket or of sentences spoken to bus drivers or people negotiating each other in a restaurant or on the street. In an earlier version of this question, the OP discussed combinatoric possibilities in relation to a 20 word sentence. Here, the OP presumably got their notional 20-word example sentence length from considering written corpora (more on this later). However, this disregards SMS and WhatsApp messages, for example, as well as emails and so forth. According to the Pew Research Centre, 18-24 year olds sent or received on average 109.5 SMS messages per day. The length of any sentences contained within such texts (a lot of the messages won’t contain any writing or may not contain full sentences) is likely to be quite short and, one suspects, the vocabulary more constrained, increasing the likelihood of their being reduplicated. For many millions of people this is going to be the largest body of writing that they produce in terms of numbers of sentences. Annually, according to Sellcell.com (in information that's easily replicable from many sources) humans currently send around 8 trillion SMS messages and 43 trillion Whatsapp messages per year. On a relatively quick back of an envelope calculation this would appear to dwarf the output of the 4 million books (which contain an average of 70-120 thousand words), and 5 million academic articles published every year as well as the estimated 4.7 billion indexed pages of the World Wide Web, most of which, of course, was not published in a single year! Without considering this written output the outcome of this investigation will be severely skewed. And we don't seem to have the corpora to be able to do so.
We shouldn't bother with writing
This brings us to a fourth point. Why consider written sentences at all? To start with many of the world's 7,000-odd languages have no writing system, and many others have had one invented but it is rarely ever used. Even in those societies in which some people write relatively often, there is still no doubt that for the vast, vast majority of people, people speak far, far more than they write. Onnela et al suggest that male and female English speakers speak around 16,000 words per day, far outreaching the most prolific of writers! The importance of this is two-fold. Firstly the chance of a sentence being repeated increases the greater the number of sentences uttered. The second is that spoken sentences are, on average, much shorter than written ones (- or the written ones that you see in large corpora  taken from specific types of texts, novels, newspapers and so forth). In a description task in Nippold (2013), the average utterance length varied between 10 and 13 words depending on the task. It's possible that in most environments it would be shorter still, not longer. In any case, the vast, vast, vast majority of sentences are spoken and not written and we shouldn't let written corpora skew or sully our data or our picture of the task at hand.
Time
Turning to the fifth point, you may have noticed that I talked about the possibility of a sentence having already been said or being said in the future. The standard varieties of many languages seem to have become fairly stabilised, perhaps due to the different types of media that they dominate, and the English of 100 years ago is barely different in any substantive way from the English of today. We might assume that things might continue in this vein for the next hundred or few hundred years too. So the question then becomes how far into the past and future do you want to look? The likelihood of a sentence being repeated obviously goes up the longer you wait, and also the greater the population becomes. There is an old addage that if a monkey bashes away randomly on a typewriter for an infinite amount of time it will eventually produce the works of Shakespeare ...
Language is a combinatorial system, but ...
Lastly, let's consider the often raised question of combinatoric possibilities. In an earlier version of this question, OP wrote:

[The fact that most sentences are said or written only once] seems obvious considering the combinatoric explosion of possible sentences that results if we multiply even a low number like 1,000 possible word-choices for each word in, say, a 20-word sentence. That's 1060 possible sentences right there, far more than even 8 billion people could say if they each said one unique sentence every second for 200,000 years, and we haven't even considered sentences of different lengths yet.

Well, we need to adjust some of these figures. First of all, as noted earlier, most spoken sentences are much shorter than 20 words. Considering the results from Nippold’s research cited above, let us assume an average sentence length of 11 words. Now, as we start to say a sentence, the words we choose radically close down the number of possibilities available to us for the following word. In addition, many word classes which will be required in the construction of grammatical sentences, for example determiners,  have very few members only some of which will be live possibilities in a given environment. In his paper Words and Rules, Steven Pinker writes:

[Our] knowledge of language is couched in abstract symbols that can embrace a vast set of concepts and can be combined freely into an even vaster set of propositions. How vast? In principle it is infinite; in practice it can be crudely estimated by assessing the number of word choices possible at each point in a sentence (roughly, 10) and raising it to a power corresponding to the maximum length of a sentence a person is likely to produce and understand, say, 20. The number is 1020 or about a hundred million trillion sentences (Pinker, 1994).

What Pinker is calculating here is the expressive power of the language, in other words the number of theoretically possible sentences. However, what we are interested in is actually uttered sentences. With this in mind let's take our notional sentence length of 11 words and use Pinker’s estimate of 10 possible word choices at any given point. This gives us 1011 possible sentences. Sentences shorter than this can be simply accommodated by positing blank words at the end of a sentence.
Now, there are currently 620 million native English speakers in the world—we will ignore the tiny percentage who can't speak because they are babies, or for other reasons—who are averaging, according to Onnela et al, 16,000 words per day.  Assuming an eleven-word average length sentence this correlates to 1455 sentences per day. And they’re doing this for 365 days of the year. This gives us a back of the envelope figure of 3.3 x 1014  English sentences uttered every year – which seems to be significantly higher than the 1011 suggested expressive capacity.
However, I do not have much faith in Pinker’s estimate of 10 possible words at any given point. His own calculation ignores the fact that the first word, or the word functioning as head of the subject noun phrase in any given sentence is not nearly so highly constrained. Having experimented with various sentences it seems that for certain words the number of possibilities is many orders higher.
But in any case, I am going to argue that such simple combinatoric calculations are deeply misleading. The reason is that they ignore frequency and probability. Although, depending on how you measure it, most adults know around 18-25,000 words, most of us only use a very few thousand in our day to day spoken utterances. In fact, it has been shown again and again, in relation to English, that just the 100 most frequent words in English account for over 50% of the text in several well-respected corpora, for example the Oxford English Corpus. The fact of the matter is that, as mentioned in this Language Log post most words are very rare. So if one is going to try to calculate how likely a spoken utterance is to be repeated, you need to know how likely a sentence is to have relatively frequent words in it and how frequent (and therefore likely to be reproduced in a given utterance) those words are going to be. Intuition and the facts just mentioned tell us, of course,  that not only are sentences like She hit him more likely to be repeated than The sesquipedalian chihuahua prevaricated, they are also more likely to be uttered in the first place and will therefore take up a large proportion of the natural language sentences that are uttered.
Because of the issue of word frequency (and construction frequency for that matter), if we are to try to calculate the likelihood of an unspecified spoken sentence being repeated (or having been said already), we would need to have a sound understanding of Zipf’s law, which correlates a words rank with its predicted frequency, and a much better understanding of probability than I could ever possible grasp. It seems to me that this is an extremely complicated issue which would be difficult, if not possible to resolve.
Parting thought
[I'm currently waiting for clarification from OP about the data below before I edit this section. The 10% mentioned below is going to be somewhat smaller, although  it's not clear how much. However, whether it's 10, 7 or 5% the general principle holds!]
I leave you with the following thought. Here is Pinker’s claim:

Virtually every sentence that a person utters or understands is a brand-new combination of words

Now, in preparation for this question, Ben Kovitz, OP, did a rough and ready search of the British National Corpus (commonly referred to as the BNC). He found that they had a total of roughly 6 million sentences, out of which roughly 600,000 were duplicates, slightly more than 10%. So, even in a relatively small corpus (compared, for example to the 19.6 billion word News on the web or NOW corpus), a full 10% of the sentences were duplicates. This therefore blasts out of the water Pinker’s claim that virtually every sentence ever uttered is unique. That 10% figure would, of course, be much higher if the corpus wasn’t distorted by an overrepresentation of written text giving an average sentence-length of 16 words. It would also be much higher in a much bigger corpus. Pinker's sold us a stinker!

Regarding the BNC experiment, OP also notes "A cursory look at the duplicates suggests that a great many are actually section headings, like "EDUCATION", "Department:", "Introduction", "Act 1, Scene 1", not sentences as we ordinarily think of them." I wonder how the results would change if sentences of, say, four words or less were removed. (Presumably this was implicit in Pinker's claim, because a great many utterances consist of "yes", "no", "I agree", "what?" etc and those are trivially not unique.)

@Draconis Oh, I missed that. Ah, I see. He's added that in while I've been writing the post!

@Draconis I agree about Yes and No and similar. They're arguably not sentences. However, I see no reason why I agree which is a fully grammatical canonical sentence should be excluded. And those complete sentence type sentences are not so trivial even if they're ubiquitous.

@Draconis I've put in a placeholder comment while I wait for Ben to let us know about what proportion of the notional dupes where actual sentences.

That's fair. I would say a better way to state the proposition in question, then, is "are most non-trivial sentences said/written only once" (define "trivial" in some appropriate way, like under N words), because the fact that "I agree" has been said many times is definitely true but also not very interesting.

@Draconis I don't think we should exclude boring sentences. My reason is this: the great 'design feature' of human language is often said to be that we can say an infinitely large number of sentences or that we can have infinitely long sentences, i.e. there is no maximal sentence length, that human language is always recursive and so an and so forth. However, although I agree that most of those claims do apply for a majority of languages, they are all trivial and also inconsequential. (continued)

@Draconis ... The genius design feature of human language is that we can use the same sentence millions and millions of times without it ever meaning the same thing,. And that at its most fundamental, human language involves the projection of a relatively small set of stories (aka 'verbs') onto the different situations we want to discuss again and again and again and again.

A corpus is meaningless for this question which, as stated, is also meaningless.  Think about your daily life in a family (if you have one living with you): how much is repetition? A lot of it is.

Thanks for the thoughtful, comprehensive answer—written while I was adding one sentence to the question! Your answer did just the kind of exploration that I was hoping to find in a research paper or book. Very impressive and interesting numbers about SMSes and much more! I was wary of framing my question as "Are most sentences unique?" because the "answer" depends on how that is construed—which tends to produce discussion (frowned upon at SE)—but your answer explored even more than I was considering. I wonder, though, how many of your sentences appeared for the first time in history. :)

Any feedback on the reason for the. downvotes? I can't improve the post without it!
